# Why are certain quantities so fundamental to physics?

Tags: energy, momentum, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, invariants

Apart from having a qualitative description of quantities such as momentum, work and energy, why are these quantities considered so fundamental? What is the reason to define them in the first place? We could define other quantities but why these specifically? They help us solve the equations of motion, is that their only significance which gives us such an important reason to give a qualitative description to them? Is it because of Noether's theorem i.e. we define these quantities because they are invariant under certain conditions? Is the qualitative description justified in any sense?

Answer (score 4):

Momentum and energy are fundamental because they are *conserved* quantities. The total momentum and the total energy of a closed system do not change with time. In a world where everything seems to change all all the time, it is nice to find that some things do *not*.

Noether’s Theorem is one way to understand why certain quantities like this are conserved. They are related to the *symmetries* of the system. Energy is conserved because of time-translation symmetry, and momentum is conserved because of spatial-translation symmetry.

Comment: Sure but why do we need to call them "Momentum", "Energy" and give a qualitative feeling for it? Why don't we just give them arbitrary symbols and start using them? Is the qualitative description justified?

Comment: Humans have always given names to the things that they think about.

Comment: I'm seeking some formal justification for these "names" and the "intuition" with which they are taught and referred to as. So would you say that these names are just names and the intuition is a scam i.e. just some way to explain the concept without introducing deeper math?

Comment: The word “momentum” simply comes from Latin words referring to movement. That seems reasonable, doesn’t it?

Comment: The word “energy” comes from a Greek word for “activity”. The words and the intuitions behind them are not “scams”. Intuition is extremely valuable, although it can be misleading. It is not worthwhile to get hung up on names of things.

Comment: You added a sentence to your question asking “Is the qualitative description justified in any sense?” This is unclear since you have not described what you were taught about these quantities. What is “*the* qualitative description”? Surely this varies from book to book and teacher to teacher. Fortunately, all agree on the math.

Comment: At an elementary level, the way physics is taught is to give a physical sense for it first (well for me at least) ... then describe this intuition in equations. But did humans come up with the equations first and then try to find some physical intuition to it? In the latter case it seems more reasonable, at least to me (being from a math background), to think concepts like "momentum" as a preserved quantity that help us solve things

Comment: You are asking more about the history of early physics than I know. Sorry. You should think of these concepts in whatever way makes sense to *you*. I am being warned to avoid an extended discussion, so I will stop now.

Comment: @tushar it is not really nice to ask new questions in the comments. Comments on questions are for clarification and improvement of the question and comments on answers are for clarification and improvement of the answer. Comments on questions are not for answers and comments on answers are not for more questions.

Comment: @tushar In the past, we came up with the physical intuitions first, because our understanding of the human-scale world around us was better than our mathematics.  Over time, that has evolved.  Nowdays it's a back and forth pattern of gathering enough data to show that the old equations aren't sufficient, creating new equations which work with the data, then bringing those equations back to the physical world with testing.

Comment: Many of these named things were named first because they had a practical use, and then they were refined from there into the equation-based form we know.

Answer (score 1):

We define any variable we please the ones you hear about, like force and momentum, are the ones which have historically proven worthwhile to pay attention to.

There are plenty of variables that have died off.  For example, in the early days of thermodynamics, it was thought that heat and cold were two different fluids.  A fire produced one, and ice produced another.  It took a while before people realized that the two sets of equations they had for heat and cold fluids could actually be just one set of equations if you treated "producing" cold as "consuming" heat.  Now, we only teach "heat."

The quantities you learn are those which offer the most bang for your buck.  You learn about force and energy because we find they are most applicable at the most fundamental levels and in the most places.  You probably don't learn about quantities like the [electrostriction coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostriction).  For one thing, it's a fourth rank tensor, and you wont learn about tensors until later.  For another, most people have absolutely no use for calculating the effects of electrostriction.  And when you do have a use for it, guess what... you'll be taught about it!

The conserved values are, in my opinion, special.  They are the closest to fundamentals as they come, because you can't just *get* them whenever you want them.  You have to take them from somewhere.  If I want to execute a Judo throw, the angular momentum (a conserved value) has to come from *somewhere*.  Often this involves using our muscles, expending energy (another conserved value).  These budgets for conserved values turn out to be quite applicable in real scenarios.

If you slip on ice. Why did you do that?  Well, you are used to being able to control the angular momentum imparted on your body thanks to the forces of friction on your foot.  Step on ice, those friction forces go away, and you suddenly must be *much* more careful with how you acquire and issue angular momentum, because you are given fewer chances to get it easily.

Going bigger, consider Delta-V.  This is how space craft measure their maneuverability.  In our daily life, delta-v is just "acceleration" and its easily acquired by pushing against the ground.  In the case of rockets, however, this acceleration is hard earned, and budgeted dearly.  You can't get Delta-V back in space.  So people learning about space travel learn about the quantity known as Delta-V.  Those of us which live on the ground (or fly in planes through the air) tend not to bother with it.